# Unable to launch app on Android 7.1.2 through appium in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, appium

**I am getting this error when I run the project :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device platform version. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/home/saurabhs/Documents/Android-SDK/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 06b271f7f0e971e3 shell getprop ro.build.version.release' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: insufficient permissions for device: user saurabhs is not in the plugdev group
```

When I change the device that has a different android version than 7.1.2,
it works fine.
Should I change change my android version?
Here is a list of jars that I have configured in the build path in eclipse

```
log4j-1.2.17.jar
bson-3.0.4.jar
extentreports-2.41.2.jar
freemarker-2.3.23.jar
jsoup-1.8.3.jar
mongodb-driver-3.0.4.jar
mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar
java-client-6.0.0.jar
poi-3.17.jar
testng-6.14.2.jar
```

**Appium Error Log**

```
[debug] [W3C] Error: Command '/home/saurabhs/Documents/Android-SDK/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s febe4347d540 shell pm clear com.tataunistore.luxury' exited with code 1 [debug] [W3C] at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:94:19) [debug] [W3C] at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13) [debug] [W3C] at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16) [debug] [W3C] at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5) [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 12846 ms - 1233
```

Comment: which appium version are you using? Can you upload your appium server log?

Comment: I am using appium version 1.12.0

Comment: and appium log is :

Comment: [debug] [W3C] Error: Command '/home/saurabhs/Documents/Android-SDK/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s febe4347d540 shell pm clear com.tataunistore.luxury' exited with code 1
[debug] [W3C]     at ChildProcess.proc.on.code (/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:94:19)
[debug] [W3C]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
[debug] [W3C]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 12846 ms - 1233

Comment: Let's try running this command alone:

```/home/saurabhs/Documents/Android-SDK/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s febe4347d540 shell pm clear com.tataunistore.luxury```

That's throwing an error that's possibly getting gobbled up at a higher level? Its output might provide insight.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the device in "MTP / File Transfer" mode and allow USB debugging so it works.

You can enable File Transfer mode by tapping on the "usb connected" notification and choosing "File Transfer (MTP)" in the dialog that appears. If no "usb connection" appears, it might be that your USB cable is faulty or is just conducting power and no data.

Regarding USB debugging, you have to enable developer options first (tap 7 times in the "Build number" in "Settings > About phone" and the menu will appear) and then enable "USB debugging", it's one of the first options in the developer settings menu.

You can check if the configuration worked by running `adb devices` in your terminal. If it shows the device as "unauthorized" you still cannot install apps through adb, and so, neither Appium. If it shows the device as "device" then it's all configured properly and you should have no permission problems.

Comment: My devices work perfectly well with USB mode set to charge only. I've set them as such because I've had reliability issues with the "Install Android File Transfer" nag screen popping up at inopportune times.

Comment: It's legit not gonna work if the device is in "charge only". Maybe usb debugging enabled appears and some adb features are available, but you *should* set it in MTP mode for all features to work.

Comment: As I'd expect, but my coworker and I were forced to do this this week to work around an issue. It worked perfectly. Perhaps it wasn't actually changed to this mode on the fly? Maybe a reboot is required or something?

Comment: I enabled File Transfer Mode, but it still doesn't work. However using adb devices command in terminal, it doesn't show as unauthorized but as a device.

Comment: Do you have multiple user accounts in the device you're using for the tests?